# generic hql select function given field and param

Tags: hql

is this valid HQL?
If not (i assume not since im getting wrong result back). How/can i achieve this generic slect transaction?

```
String hql = "SELECT * from users Where :searchCriteria = :searchString";
            List q = session.createSQLQuery(hql).addEntity(Users.class)
                    .setParameter("searchField", searchCriteria)
                    .setParameter("searchString", searchString).list();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this hql,

```
Criteria cr= session.createCriteria(Users.class);
cr.add(Restrictions.eq("searchField", searchCriteria);
cr.add(Restrictions.eq("searchString", searchString);
List<Users> user_data=(List<Users>)cr.list();
```